# How do I filter or remove logging of ActiveJob arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport, rails-activejob

I'm using Rails' ActiveJob, and one of my jobs take a raw email as input. When debugging, this can result in a huge amount of noise in my application log. How can I avoid that?

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued EmailParserJob (Job ID: 9678f343-c876-4f9f-9cc7-db440634e178) to DelayedJob(default) with arguments: "NOISE"
```

Comment: Did any of the provided answers work for you?

Comment: nope, ended up ditching ActiveJob and bound myself to Delayed::Job.

Comment: In addition to being noisy, it's also a potential security concern if you are logging the content of private communications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Rails 6.1, you can turn off the logging with `log_arguments` like the below. This will turn off logging the arguments for all the jobs derived from `ApplicationJob`, You can also set it on per job basis.

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  self.log_arguments = false
end
```

Reference:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37660

Answer (score 8):

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activejob/lib/active_job/logging.rb#L10

```
ActiveJob::Base.logger = Logger.new(nil)
```

Comment: @DenisTataurov That can potentially lead to problems if some code expects `ActiveJob::Base.logger` to quack like a `Logger` without checking for `nil`.

Comment: This works well, add it inside your own subclass of ActiveJob, like: self.logger = Logger.new(nil) if Rails.env.test?

Comment: I ended up combining this with another answer and use this in a particular job to disable logging: `self.logger = Logger.new(IO::NULL) unless ENV['ENABLE_UPDATE_ONLINE_STATUS_LOGS'] == true`

Answer (score 6):

One thing that may be useful to note here:  In any instance of a class that is subclassed from (Rails 5.1) **ActiveJob::Base** (or, any class instance called by a class subclassed from ActiveJob::Base) The normal `Rails.logger.info('log this')` commands are going to get logged to the rails console (presumably via STDOUT).

I haven't quite figured out the mechanism that causes this hijacking of Rails.logger, but you can switch to ActiveJob::Base.logger and use the knowledge of this: (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b205ea2dc6c70b2b8e2134640e3056ed33fdc6be/activejob/lib/active_job/logging.rb#L13) to change the behavior as you wish.

So, this allows you to log as you want:

1) Include `require "active_job/logging"` in your application.rb

2) In **config/development.rb** (or whatever environments you want) include this line:

```
config.active_job.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new("log/#{Rails.env}.log"))
```

3) Any logging inside of subclasses of ActiveJob, use this for logging:

```
ActiveJob::Base.logger.info('(MyJob) Inside of a job but not going to STDOUT')
```

If anyone can point out the code that explains why `Rails.logger.info` behaves differently when inside of an **ActiveJob** class that would be some good reading.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the only way is to override ActiveJob's [internal logging method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/lib/active_job/logging.rb#L87):

```
class ActiveJob::Logging::LogSubscriber
  private def args_info(job)
    ''
  end
end
```

Put it somewhere into `app/initializers/active_job_logger_patch.rb`.

Comment: This did end up working for me, but I had to add this to my initializer in Rails 5.0.2:  `require 'active_job/logging'`

Answer (score 5):

I used `after_initialize` to hook beforehand. It turned out to work only in `perform_start` method but not `enqueue`.
Using `on_load` method to hook works. I think it's the lazyload feature in Rails causing the class to be loaded after the override.

```
ActiveSupport.on_load :active_job do
  class ActiveJob::Logging::LogSubscriber
    private def args_info(job)
      # override this method to filter arguments shown in app log
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the following recommendation [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/e9p8lx/how_do_i_stop_activejobsidekiq_from_polluting_my/):

```
ActiveJob::Base.logger = Logger.new(IO::NULL)
```

Seems to be better than passing a `nil`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like they added the feature [Add an option to disable logging for jobs with sensitive arguments](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37660/files) in Rail 6. This would prevent any arguments from appearing in the log lines.

Edit: To use this with ActionMailer, [using a custom mailer job](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/01/15/rails-5-2-allows-mailers-to-use-custom-active-job-class.html) might work, haven't tested this myself yet.